# Как заголовке окна отобразить текст из TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в заголовке окна отобразить текст из TextBox который будет меняться?

TextBox отображает путь к открытой папке в компоненте webBrowser. Нужно сделать так чтобы этот адрес брался из TextBox (или можно сразу из webBrowser) и отображался в заголовке окна, но он должен меняться в заголовке как только я перейду в другую папку.

Comment: Собственные мысли как решить эту проблему есть?

Comment: this.Text = textBox1.Text; Но в какое событие добавить?

Comment: Какие события вы рассматривали на эту роль?

Comment: Все, но какое из то самое не знаю. Потому и спрашиваю. Может вообще не так все думаю.

Comment: Даю подсказку где смотреть список событий - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А мне казалось этот код нужно в события формы вставлять.

Comment: меняется текст где? в TextBox. Значит его события и нужно смотреть. Разобрались с тем, какое из них вам нужно?

Comment: Стоп. Текст в TextBox и так меняется уже. Мне нужно чтобы этот текст переносился в заголовок формы/окна и в случае изменения текста в TextBox текст должен поменяться и в заголовке.

Comment: @River, событие TextChanged смотрите. Простите, не выдержал :)

Comment: @Андрей ;D (похоже вопросов будет еще много, так что свои педагогические способности еще успею потренировать))

Comment: Смешно... И все же вопросов больше нет. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Плюсую вопрос, наконец удалось встретит юного "падована", способного к учебе.

Comment: @River предлагаю вам написать ответ на свой вопрос =)

Comment: @River возможно вам будет интересно, на SO существует система чатов, где тоже можно задавать вопросы и принимать участие в обсуждениях. Вот, например, комната для C# - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--

Answer (score 0):

this.Text = textBox1.Text; в событие TextChanged.